# File Path Help for Flask app and python request

Tags: flask, python-requests

I created a simple site to upload .csv files. trying to use Flask behind the scenes to call an endpoint which uses the data from the uploaded file as the input.

I can't figure out how to get that file path right:

```
    with open(**HELP HERE**, "r") as file:
        data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
        data.pop(0)
        output = []
```

Here is the code in it's entirety, save the authorization token.

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, 
send_file
import requests
import csv
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

def call_api_and_generate_files(csv_path):
    url = "https://api.6sense.com/v1/enrichment/people"

    with open(csv_path, "r") as file:
        data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
        data.pop(0)
        output = []


        for i in range(len(data)):
            payload = str(data[i])
            payload = payload[2:]
            payload = payload[:-2]
            payload = 'email=' + payload
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-
```

urlencoded',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Authorization': 'Token
'
}

```
            response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            output.append(response.text)

        count_missing_emails = 0
        count_no_return = 0
        count_missing_domain = 0
        count_missing_phone = 0
        count_missing_title = 0
        count_missing_level = 0
        count_missing_function = 0
        count_error_calls = 0

        output_csv_path = 'output.csv'
        counts_csv_path = 'counts.csv'

        with open(output_csv_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            writeout = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
            writeout.writerow(["JSON Return", "Email", "Domain", "Phone", "Job Title", "Job Level", "Job Function"])
            for li in output:
                partition_email = li.partition('"email":"')[2]
                partition_email = partition_email.partition('"')[0]
                partition_domain = li.partition('"domain":"')[2]
                partition_domain = partition_domain.partition('"')[0]
                partition_phone = li.partition('"phone":"')[2]
                partition_phone = partition_phone.partition('"')[0]
                partition_title = li.partition('"title":"')[2]
                partition_title = partition_title.partition('"')[0]
                partition_level = li.partition('"level":"')[2]
                partition_level = partition_level.partition('"')[0]
                partition_function = li.partition('"function":"')[2]
                partition_function = partition_function.partition('"')[0]

                if li != "" and "\"error\"" not in li:
                    writeout.writerow([li, partition_email, partition_domain, partition_phone, partition_title, partition_level, partition_function])
                if "\"email\":\"\"" in li:
                    count_missing_emails += 1
                if li == "":
                    count_no_return += 1
                if "\"domain\":\"\"" in li:
                    count_missing_domain += 1
                if "\"phone\":\"\"" in li:
                    count_missing_phone += 1
                if "\"title\":\"\"" in li:
                    count_missing_title += 1
                if "\"level\":\"\"" in li:
                    count_missing_level += 1
                if "\"function\":\"\"" in li:
                    count_missing_function += 1
                if "\"error\"" in li:
                    count_error_calls += 1

        with open(counts_csv_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as myfile2:
            writeout2 = csv.writer(myfile2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records From File: {}".format(len(data))])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Calls Made: {}".format(len(output))])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Calls Returned With Firmographics: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Calls Not Returned/Matched: {}".format(count_no_return)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Calls With Errors: {}".format(count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records Returned With Email: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_missing_emails - count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records Returned With Domain: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_missing_domain - count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records Returned With Phone: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_missing_phone - count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records Returned With Title: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_missing_title - count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records Returned With Level: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_missing_level - count_error_calls)])
            writeout2.writerow(["# of Records Returned With Function: {}".format(len(output) - count_no_return - count_missing_function - count_error_calls)])

    return counts_csv_path

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if 'csv-file' not in request.files:
        return "No file part"

    csv_file = request.files['csv-file']

    if csv_file.filename == '':
        return "No selected file"

    # Save the uploaded CSV file
    uploaded_csv_path = os.path.join('/Users/patrickcunning/PycharmProjects/frontendTEST', 'uploaded.csv')
    csv_file.save(uploaded_csv_path)


    # Call API and generate files
    counts_csv_path = call_api_and_generate_files(uploaded_csv_path)

    # Read the counts.csv file and pass its contents to the template
    with open(counts_csv_path, 'r') as counts_file:
        counts_data = counts_file.read()

    return render_template('index.html', counts_data=counts_data)

@app.route('/download_output')
def download_output():
    # Logic to send the output.csv file to the user
    return send_file('output.csv', as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can't seem to locate the file that gets uploaded and place the file name in the correct spot.

From the website, it will allow me to upload a csv. However, when I click the submit button, I'm hit with an error 'file not found'. Here's the html of the site if that helps too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSV Upload and API Call</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload CSV and Perform API Call</h1>
    <form id="upload-form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="csv-file" accept=".csv">
        <button type="submit">Upload and Call API</button>
    </form>

    <div id="results" class="hidden">
        <h2>Results from counts.csv:</h2>
        <pre id="counts-results"></pre>
        <a href="{{ url_for('download_output') }}" download>Download output.csv</a>
    </div>

    <script>
        // JavaScript to show/hide results div after successful API call
        const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
        const countsResults = document.getElementById('counts-results');

        function showResults(resultsText) {
            countsResults.textContent = resultsText;
            resultsDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't tell us where you save your upload, we can't help you with the path. Please expand your question with the meaningful part. Depending on the requirements, it is also possible to read the file without saving it. That may be an option for you.

Comment: updated-  @Detlef Thanks for clarification. I'm a newbie.

Comment: The path seems correct to me. Is there an error message?

Comment: Thanks for confirming, the error message comes after I hit the "submit" button (which should kick off the actual api call) on the website. It tells me that the file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't reproduce the error message.
For reasons of practicability, I used the [`app.instance_path`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#instance-folders) to upload and it worked.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
import csv, os 

app = Flask(__name__)

def call_api_and_generate_files(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
        data.pop(0)
    
    print(data)
    
    # ...

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('csv-file')
        if file and file.filename.endswith('.csv'):
            path = os.path.join(app.instance_path, file.filename)
            file.save(path)

            result = call_api_and_generate_files(path)
            

            # ...

    return render_template('upload.html', **locals())
```

If you are interested in reading the file without saving, here is an example.
The [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) is required to read the binary as text.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
import csv, io

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('csv-file')
        if file and file.filename.endswith('.csv'):
            with io.TextIOWrapper(file) as f:
                data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
                data.pop(0)

            print(data)

            # ...

    return render_template('upload.html', **locals())
```

The HTML code is the same as yours in both examples.
Good luck.